# Multiple PDF export with single JRXML

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am using *iReport* for designing the JRXML and *JasperReports Server* for report scheduling.

I have developed the simple single JRXML in *iReport* with SQL query that execute query and get the record and generate single pdf.

Now i have different type of records like :

```
DEPT     NAME    Salary 
---------------------------
HR       MR XYZ    500000
MFG      MR PQR    300000
HR       MR ABC    400000
EDU      MR DEF    350000
EDU      MR SSS    400000
```

Now my requirement is to generate individual pdf for each department. Means one pdf contain only HR related data other must contain only EDU related data etc.

How can do it with *iReport* and *JasperReports Server*?

Comment: How do you use the reports? Do you have a Java code managing PDF printing?

Comment: No, No java java code. I am using Jasper server as i have mentioned to schedule the report.

Answer (score 0):

You can parametrize your query. If I understand correctly, and choosing department is a matter of simple WHERE clause you can add to the query:

```
WHERE dept like $P{DEPT_PARAM}
```

And pass that parameter from jasperserver as needed ("%" for when you need to print for all the departments)

Comment: Thanks @Deltharis... But i want a individual pdf for each department. How Jasper server will do this. Because it is scheduled report with dynamic input parameter

Comment: Umm... You schedule more pdfs with different parameters?

Comment: Yes.. You are right.. But if in future there is another Departmet add then again i have to schedule other report with that newly added parameter ..